# Suppressing page range of the reference

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm using `biblatex-gost` package, `gost-footnote` style. If I'm citing some bibliography item for which the `pages` field is filled (usually an article, book chapter, materials in conference proceedings...) and at the same time specifying a particular page as a postnote argument, the reference in the footnote includes both the page range of the article (or another type of item) in a journal and the page I specified. According to GOST, in cases like this the page range should be suppressed. In other words, I want to get

Author Name. Article Title // Journal name. Year. Vol. 1, no 2. P. 10

instead of

Author Name. Article Title // Journal name. Year. Vol. 1, no 2. Pp. 5-15.  P. 10.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{extreport}

\usepackage{cmap}                           
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\frenchspacing

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@article{cummings2004argument,
    langid = {english},
    title={Argument as Cognition: A Putnamian Criticism of Dale Hample’s Cognitive Conception of Argument},
    author={Cummings, Louise},
    journal={Argumentation},
    volume={18},
    number={3},
    pages={331--348},
    year={2004},
    publisher={Springer}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,sorting=nyt,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=999,style=gost-footnote,language=auto,autolang=other,bibstyle=gost-numeric,opcittracker=false,pagetracker]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

some text some text some\footcite[P.~335]{cummings2004argument} text some text some text some text

\printbibliography
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex-gost` already does that for you, if you let it set the "P.~" prefix automatically. Use

```
\footcite[335]{sigfridsson}
```

instead of adding the prefix manually (`\footcite[P.~335]{sigfridsson}`).

This is controlled by the `citepages` option in `biblatex-gost` (this option is also available in the `verbose`-flavoured standard styles), where it is set to `omit`, i.e. it omits the `pages` field if the postnote contains a page reference. Other possible options are `permit` where the `pages` field is always printed; `suppress` always suppresses the `pages` field; and `separate`, where the postnote is separated from the `pages` field by "especially" if it contains a page number. See [the `verbose` style documentation for examples](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/70-style-verbose-biber.pdf).

Comment: I looked through the `biblatex` documentation and couldn't find any mention of it. Yet it warks :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @David Yes, the option `citepages` is only properly explained in the style docus (examples), the `biblatex` manual only touches on the subject very, very briefly.